# How to extract counts as a vector from a table in R?

Tags: r, frequency

I'm trying to write a function to extract the frequencies of this table:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
30 22  9 12  2  5  1 16
```

So I want to get `c(30, 22, 9, 12, 2, 5, 1, 16)`.

The table changes each time I run the function, so I need something that can extract the information from the table automatically, so I don't have write a c() function each time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's create a results object from `table()` and examine it:

```
> set.seed(42)                          ## be reproducible
> X <- sample(1:5, 50, replace=TRUE)    ## our data
> table(X)                              ## our table
X
 1  2  3  4  5 
 7  6  9 10 18 
> str(table(X))                         ## look at structure of object
 'table' int [1:5(1d)] 7 6 9 10 18
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ X: chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
> as.integer(table(X))                  ## and just convert to vector
[1]  7  6  9 10 18
> as.numeric(table(X))                  ## or use `numeric()`
[1]  7  6  9 10 18
>
```

And for completeness, two more ways to get the data:

```
> unname(table(X))                      ## jdropping names reduces to the vector
[1]  7  6  9 10 18
> table(X)[]                            ## or simply access it
[1]  7  6  9 10 18
>
```

Comment: Good answer. And use `as.numeric(names(table(data$variable)))` to catch the unique values.

Comment: Just to note that if you have an ordered variable as the basis for the table, as.numeric() will remove the ordering information.  That may be a reason to choose (or not) that option.